Is there an Equivalent to HubName attribute in .NET 8 SignalR?
I have a SignalR Hub (.NET 8) and in order to work properly with proxies on the client I need to set it's name to a lower-case using something like [HubName("hubname")] in previous versions. I can't find such attribute in Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR. Are there any alternatives to this in .NET 8?
The attribute is defined in Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Hubs As shown here.
Is it possible to use this namespace and attribute in .net 8 or will it break?

ASP.NET Core SignalR was completely rewritten along with ASP.NET Core itself. This change was introduced long before .NET 8. You'll have to find what implements the same feature, not the same mechanism. Also check Differences between ASP.NET SignalR and ASP.NET Core SignalR

Use the following way to map hubs in .NET 8
app.MapHub<MyHub>("/myHubRoute");

